# Delete files according to create date

Tags: android, date, delete-file

I want to delete the files which were created today. So how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   File f = new File("somefile.txt");

   if(f.lastModified() > DAY_START && f.lastModified() < DAY_END){
        f.delete();
    }
```

WHERE

DAY_START - long value of day start time

DAY_END - long value of day end time

HOPE it help you!!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what you mean with "Long value of day start time"?

Comment: I meen current time in millis. You can get it with System.currentTimeMillis() .http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()